# Using Team Foundation Server Merge tool on any files

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, merge

Is it possible to use the merge tool for any two files, in example `c:/1.txt` and `c:/2.txt` on my local machine?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: no how would you expect it to work on [base 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) or binaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vsDiffMerge.exe in path "Microsoft Visual Studio XXX\Common7\IDE" is the thing which visual studio uses to compare and merge the files.

You can use it by starting the vsDiffMerge.exe with right command line. Here is the [blog post](http://roadtoalm.com/2013/10/22/use-visual-studio-as-your-diff-and-merging-tool-for-local-files/) explaining how to do that. Note that the merge tool isn't independent, it will still open in visual studio only.

The syntax is like this:

```
"%VS110COMNTOOLS%/../IDE/vsdiffmerge.exe" "File1" "File2" 

"FileThatServesAsBase" "FileThatServesasTarget" /m
```

For Example

```
"%VS110COMNTOOLS%/../IDE/vsdiffmerge.exe" "Person Source.cs" 

"Person Target.cs" "Person Source.cs" "Person Source.cs" /m
```

Syntax and example pulled from above mentioned blog post.